# Resources for digging in GWT's Uibinder and Declarative UI

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I am a student getting started with web development with GWT. I have previous experience with Java however I am no UI design experience.

However I believe I can catch up on CSS easily.

I was browsing the official Google's UiBinder document, which is very concise(one page). I am not able to figure out much just from this document. It might be that things are not much obvious to me at the moment due to lack of experience in this field.

How should I dig deeper and get hang of designing UI with uibinder? 
Any resources and strategies can be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try using GWT designer which is part of the Google Plugin for Eclipse.  It'll add handlers to buttons / forms / widgets for you and populate uifields in the Java classes. I've found just playing around with it helped me quickly find UIBinder features. You can easily switch between XML and design mode if you want to see what it's creating for you.

Comment: GWT designer is very buggy, it crashes even when parsing the sample's .ui.xmL file.